# Find the rotation matrix R that minimizes $\Sigma(x_i^TR{x'}_i)^2$ given 3D vectors $x'_i$ and $x_i$ for i = 1...n

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, vectors, rotations, matrix-decomposition

Basically, the question is about finding the rotation matrix that can align one set of 3D vectors as perpendicular as possible to another set of vectors.

My gut feeling is that there should be a closed-form solution, e.g., using SVD or the property of trace... Is there anyone who knows a closed-form solution to this problem (or an idea)?

Comment: Not sure it’s the same as what you’re asking but have you heard of the (orthogonal) Procrustes problem?

Comment: @David M. Yes I heard of it, which is why I thought the closed-form solution may have to do with SVD or trace properties. But I cannot find a direct link to this problem...