# Rotate set of vectors to a set of planes defined by their normal vectors.

Tags: geometry, optimization, manifolds, rotations

Given a set of unitary vectors $\{a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n\}$ and a set of normals $\{n_1, n_2, \ldots, n_n\}$ (all vectors are in $\mathbb{R}^3$), I am trying to find the rotation matrix $R\in SO(3)$ that best aligns each vector $a_i$ with the planes defined by $n_i$. In this case, all planes pass through the origin.

An example of "best" alignment could be the one that minimizes the projections of the vectors in the least squares sense:
$$
R = \arg\min_{R} \sum_{i}(n_i^\top R a_i)^2, \qquad\text{s.t. } R\in SO(3)~.
$$
However, based on previous questions (such as [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3208568/find-the-rotation-matrix-r-that-minimizes-sigmax-itrx-i2-given-3d-vect) and [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4552983/find-a-rotation-matrix-that-makes-two-sets-of-vectors-perpendicular-to-eachother)), this expression seems to be difficult to solve in closed form.

I feel that there may be other better optimization criteria that could lead to a closed-form solution. Ideally, the criteria should still minimize the distance of the points $\{a_i\}_i$ to the planes defined by $\{n_i\}_i$, so that the rotation would still be optimal with this criteria.

This is a related visualization where two vectors, $a_1$ and $a_2$, are rotated via $R$ such that they lie on the planes defined by the normal vectors $n_1$ and $n_2$ (the ideal case):

[image]

---

*Edit* 
This is the python code that I have used to test the idea proposed by @MauricioCeleLopezBelon. Unfortunately, as long as the code has no bugs, it does not seem to work.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import special_ortho_group as SO

# create unitary 3d points (the set {a_1, a_2 ... a_n}).
npoints = 10
a = np.random.rand(3, npoints)
a /= np.linalg.norm(a, axis=0, keepdims=True)

# Get exemplar normal vectors. For that:
# 1) sample a random rotation matrix R (the one that we want to estimate).
R = SO(3).rvs()
# 2) rotate each a_i with it.
a_rot = R @ a
# 3) create normal vectors of a plane to which each a_rot_i belongs.
n = np.zeros((3, npoints))
n[0] = -a_rot[1]
n[1] = a_rot[0]
n /= np.linalg.norm(n, axis=0, keepdims=True)  # normalization

# orthogonally project each given point to the planes defined by the normals.
a_proj = a - (a * n).sum(axis=0, keepdims=True) * n

# align with SVD (solve Wahba's problem -- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wahba%27s_problem).
B = np.sum(a_proj.T[..., None] @ a.T[:, None], axis=0)
U, d, VT = np.linalg.svd(B)
M = np.eye(3)
M[2, 2] = np.linalg.det(U) * np.linalg.det(VT)
R_est = U @ M @ VT

print(f"True rotation:\n{R}\n")
print(f"Estimated rotation:\n{R_est}\n")

"""
Exemplar output

True rotation:
[[ 0.74085984  0.51771055  0.42790476]
 [-0.4977192   0.85095016 -0.16780769]
 [-0.45100143 -0.08865444  0.88810928]]

Estimated rotation:
[[ 0.83871159  0.54320098 -0.03867256]
 [-0.54101482  0.82301563 -0.1730556 ]
 [-0.06217585  0.16606616  0.98415253]]

"""
```

Comment: Because of the identity $\| \bf{a} \times \bf{b}\|^2 = \|\bf{a}\|^2 \|\bf{b}\|^2 - (\bf{a} \cdot \bf{b})^2$, your two formulations are equivalent up to a constant term.

Comment: @CharlesHudgins I see, thanks for the feedback. That formulation clearly does not help.

Comment: What about projecting each vector $a_i$ to the plane defined by $n_i$ getting the $a'_i$  and then find the best rotation aligning $a_i$ with $a'_i$ by SVD?

Comment: @MauricioCeleLopezBelon Thank you for the idea. I have tried to test it with a simple simulation (see the added code in the question), but unfortunately, it doesn't seem to work well. It only appears to work when the rotation is the identity matrix.

Comment: You can also try this thing: find the best rotation aligning $a_i$ with $n_i$ then add $\pi /2$ to rotation angle while keeping rotation axis fixed. You will need to use the logarithm and exponential of $R$.

Comment: @MauricioCeleLopezBelon Thanks again for the idea, I really appreciate your help. I see that following this approach, we would end up with a rotation matrix that projects the points $a_i$ to their corresponding planes by minimizing a certain error. However, I apologize that this is not a sufficient condition in my case (I have updated it).

Concretely, I want to minimize the distance of all vectors to their corresponding planes. However, if we use intermediate points as reference (the normal vectors, or projections), the minimized error would not be optimal, given the previous criteria.

Comment: This might be of interest https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4651624/solving-2d-wahba-least-squares-with-weights/4651878#4651878

Comment: @Faaz thank you for the pointer. 
I see that one of the optimizations involved and solved there is, adapting the notation, similar to $$\max_R \sum_i n_i^\top R a_i$$
This may be related to what I am looking for: $$\min_R \sum_i (n_i^\top R a_i)^2,$$
but I feel that the squared terms complicate the things significantly (because of this, I am open to other minimizations).

Answer (score 1):

Any rotation matrix can be specified in terms of three angles $\theta, \phi, \beta $ as follows

$ R = \begin{bmatrix} c_3 c_2 c_1 - s_3 s_2 && -s_3 c_2 c_1 - c_3 s_2 && s_1 c_2 \\ c_3 s_2 c_1 + s_3 c_2 && - s_3 s_2 c_1 + c_3 c_2 && s_1 s_2 \\ - c_3 s_1 && s_3 s_1 && c_1 \end{bmatrix}$

where $c_1 = \cos(\theta), s_1 = \sin(\theta), c_2 = \cos(\phi), s_2 = \sin(\phi), c_3 = \cos(\beta) , s_3 = \sin(\beta) $

Define the objective function as

$ f(\theta, \phi, \beta) = \displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^n (n_i^T R a_i)^2 $

Find the partial derivatives of $f$ with respect to $\theta, \phi, \beta $

$\dfrac{\partial f }{\partial \theta} = \displaystyle 2 \sum_{i=1}^n (n_i^T R a_i) ( n_i^T \dfrac{ \partial R }{\partial \theta} a_i )  $

$\dfrac{\partial f }{\partial \phi} = \displaystyle 2 \sum_{i=1}^n (n_i^T R a_i) ( n_i^T \dfrac{ \partial R }{\partial \phi} a_i ) $

$\dfrac{\partial f }{\partial \beta} = \displaystyle 2 \sum_{i=1}^n (n_i^T R a_i) ( n_i^T \dfrac{ \partial R }{\partial \beta} a_i ) $

Now you can use the simple steepest descent algorithm to minimize $f$.  I did that for $n = 3$ and it resulted in a solution that I verified. The matrix $R$ that I obtained resulted in $f = 0 $. I also found that the solution $R$ is not unique if $n = 3$, but I think it will  be unique for $n \gt 3 $.

Comment: Thank you for for your time and help. I agree that with this approach we would be able to obtain a good estimate of the rotation matrix (+1). 
However, I am hoping for a closed-form solution such that the rotation is optimal given the criterion in the question.

Comment: This would be a nice result that's worth publishing in a journal.